# Locating specifc strings in text files then deleting

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program where the user can add usernames and passwords to a text file and then also delete usernames and passwords in the text file. At the moment I do not know how to delete a line of code and keep the same text file and the only way to delete it is to get the user to input the username they want to delete and then the password and username are deleted. My code so far:(In this code I have already made the username and password checking functions work.) Thanks for any help :)

```
import re
def UsernameChecking():
    print("\nYour Username must have no blank spaces and must be less than 20 characters long")
    ab = False
    while not (ab):
        global Username
        Username = input("Please enter what you would like your username to be:\n")
        if len(Username) > 20:
            print("You username must be under 20 characters long") 
        elif re.search('[ ]',Username):
            print("There is not allowed to be any blank spaces in your username")
        else:
            print("Your username has been accepted!")
            ab = True 
def PasswordChecking():
    print("\nYour password must be at least 6 characters. \nIt also must be 12 or less characters")
    ac = False 
    while not (ac):
        global Password 
        Password = input("Please enter what you would like your password to be:\n")
        if len(Password) < 6:
            print("Your password must be 6 or more characters long")
        elif len(Password) > 12:
            print("Your password must be 12 or less characters long")
        else:
            print("Your password has been accepted!")
            ac = True

def CreateFile():
    f = open("UsernameDatabase.txt","w")
    f.close()

def AddingData():
    f = open("UsernameDatabase.txt", "a")
    f.write("\n\nUsername:" + (Username))
    f.write("\nPassword:" + (Password))
    f.close()#closes the file

def DeletingData():
    DeleteRequest = input("What Username and password would you like to delete. PLease enter the username:\n")
    f = open("UsernameDatabase.txt", "r+")

def RunningProgram():
    zz = False
    while not (zz):
        Q = input("Do you want to add a username and password to the file?\n")
        if Q == "Y":
            UsernameChecking()
            PasswordChecking()
            AddingData()
        else:
            zz = True

RunningProgram()
DeletingData()
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete usernames and passwords from the file:

```
data = [i.strip("\n").split(":") for i in open("UsernameDatabase.txt")]

user_name_to_delete = "something"

password_to_delete = "something"

f = open('UsernameDatabase.txt', 'w')
for entry in data:
    if entry[-1] != user_name_to_delete or entry[-1] != password_to_delete:
        f.write(':'.join(entry)+'\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: When I run it with this code it deletes all the usernames not just the one I want to delete

Comment: @Matt could you post a sample of your input file?

Comment: @Ajaz1234 Don't worry I think I have fixed it